# JBoss 7.0 Web profile appilcation doesn't start

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

I'm trying to start JBoss Web profile example application 'GestionFormation'. And got such exception:

```
   15:18:30,756 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."GestionFomationWeb.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."GestionFomationWeb.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "GestionFomationWeb.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:121)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class com.lo54.servlet.HomeServlet
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.EEModuleClassDescription$DefaultConfigurator.configure(EEModuleClassDescription.java:144)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.EEClassConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEClassConfigurationProcessor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:115)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lutbm/lo54/session/ManageCourseSessionBeanLocal;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2387) [:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1796) [:1.7.0_40]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: utbm.lo54.session.ManageCourseSessionBeanLocal from [Module "deployment.GestionFomationWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:330)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:307)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:101)
    ... 13 more

15:18:31,155 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) Deployment of "GestionFomationWeb.war" was rolled back with failure message {"Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"GestionFomationWeb.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"GestionFomationWeb.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"GestionFomationWeb.war\""},"Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.comp.GestionFomationWeb.GestionFomationWeb.GestionFomationWeb.ValidatorFactory missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.GestionFomationWeb.GestionFomationWeb ]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.GestionFomationWeb.GestionFomationWeb.GestionFomationWeb.Validator missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.GestionFomationWeb.GestionFomationWeb ]"]}
15:18:31,157 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Stopped deployment GestionFomationWeb.war in 5ms
15:18:31,162 ERROR [org.jboss.as.deployment] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) {"Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"GestionFomationWeb.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"GestionFomationWeb.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"GestionFomationWeb.war\""},"Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.comp.GestionFomationWeb.GestionFomationWeb.GestionFomationWeb.ValidatorFactory missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.GestionFomationWeb.GestionFomationWeb ]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.GestionFomationWeb.GestionFomationWeb.GestionFomationWeb.Validator missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.GestionFomationWeb.GestionFomationWeb ]"]}}}
15:21:22,188 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (pool-1-thread-18) Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "GestionFomationWeb.war")]): java.util.NoSuchElementException: No child 'runtime-name' exists
    at org.jboss.dmr.ModelValue.requireChild(ModelValue.java:362)
    at org.jboss.dmr.ObjectModelValue.requireChild(ObjectModelValue.java:298)
    at org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode.require(ModelNode.java:703)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentDeployHandler.execute(DeploymentDeployHandler.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:351)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.doCompleteStep(OperationContextImpl.java:298)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.completeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:223)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.CompositeOperationHandler.execute(CompositeOperationHandler.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:351)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.doCompleteStep(OperationContextImpl.java:298)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.completeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:223)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$DefaultPrepareStepHandler.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:350)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:351)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.doCompleteStep(OperationContextImpl.java:298)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.completeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:223)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:119)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:154)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.access$100(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.call(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:114)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.call(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [:1.7.0_40]

16:06:04,441 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (pool-1-thread-19) Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "GestionFomationWeb.war")]): java.util.NoSuchElementException: No child 'runtime-name' exists
    at org.jboss.dmr.ModelValue.requireChild(ModelValue.java:362)
    at org.jboss.dmr.ObjectModelValue.requireChild(ObjectModelValue.java:298)
    at org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode.require(ModelNode.java:703)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentDeployHandler.execute(DeploymentDeployHandler.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:351)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.doCompleteStep(OperationContextImpl.java:298)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.completeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:223)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.CompositeOperationHandler.execute(CompositeOperationHandler.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:351)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.doCompleteStep(OperationContextImpl.java:298)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.completeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:223)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$DefaultPrepareStepHandler.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:350)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:351)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.doCompleteStep(OperationContextImpl.java:298)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.completeStep(OperationContextImpl.java:223)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:119)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:154)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.access$100(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.call(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:114)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.call(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [:1.7.0_40]
```

[UPDATE TO SHOW MY DATA SOURCE CONFIGURATION]

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
      <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar"/>
      </resources>
      <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
      </dependencies>
    </module>
```

standalone.xml

```
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="MysqlDS">
       <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/gestion_formation</connection-url>
       <driver>mysql</driver>
          <security>
             <user-name>root</user-name>
             <password>*******</password>
         </security>
        <validation>
             <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
        </validation>
   </datasource>

<drivers>
 <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">  
 <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>                 
 </driver>  
</drivers>
```

How can I fix this issue?
thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the class utbm.lo54.session.ManageCourseSessionBeanLocal located? JBoss expects it to be in the GestionFomationWeb.war, but does not find it there. Is it really a part of the war?

Comment: utbm.lo54.session.ManageCourseSessionBeanLocal is located in an EJB project named GestionFormationEJB in the same workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this happens because of a data source misconfiguration - a problem I'm also suffering. The error message text is wrong and confusing. See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3190

Comment: the issue you linked was fixed almost two years ago, before jboss 7.1.1 release. it doesn't mention data source configurations either...

Comment: Thanks @fleddingCoder, even if your link doesn't mention data source configuration. My problem was data source configuration.

Comment: @eis getting the same error since yesterday on JBoss AS 7.1.1

Comment: I'm just saying that your link is probably unrelated.

Comment: @iPisix could you tell what was exactly wrong with? maybe we could open an issue about it and get it fixed